# Handling Null Fields in MVC + SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a table that contains certain fields with null values. I have tried handling these errors using the Dbnull but to no avail. The View is displayed but now all fields are blank.

Below is a snippet:

```
protected MemberViewModel ReadValue(SqlDataReader reader)
{
    MemberViewModel obj = new MemberViewModel();

    obj.Client = (string)reader["Client"];
    obj.PolicyNo = (DBNull.Value.ToString());
    _ = reader["PolicyType"] == DBNull.Value ? (short)0 : (short)reader["PolicyType"];
    _ = reader["InsurerName"] == DBNull.Value ? "" : reader["InsurerName"].ToString();
    _ = reader["RenewalDate"] == DBNull.Value ? (DateTime.MinValue) : Convert.ToDateTime(reader["RenewalDate"]);
    obj.Status = (string)reader["Status"];
    obj.Telephone = (DBNull.Value.ToString());

    return obj;
}
```

The value of `obj` is:

```
Client: "& BEYOND LTD" 
InsurerName: null 
PolicyNo: "" 
PolicyType: null 
RenewalDate: null 
Status: "LAPSED" 
Telephone: ""
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at [IDataReaderExtensions](https://github.com/Peled-Zohar/ADONETHelper/blob/master/ADONETHelper/ADONETHelper/IDataReaderExtensions.cs)...

Comment: Just for clarification. Can I implement an IsDBNull within the same context because am starting to think maybe using DBNull, declares the fields to be considered null? From my database table, all fields contain values

Comment: Please show us the `CREATE TABLE` script for the table. I'd also **strongly** suggest using Dapper, and let it manage `null`s for you.

Answer (score 0):

I finally maneuvered around the code. Thanks for the tips though

```
        if (reader["Client"] != DBNull.Value)
        {
            obj.Client = (string)reader["Client"];
        }

        if (reader["PolicyNo"] != DBNull.Value)
        {
            obj.PolicyNo = (string)reader["PolicyNo"];
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (reader["PolicyType"] != DBNull.Value)
        {
            obj.PolicyType = (short)reader["PolicyType"];
        }
```